# Present perfect and past perfect

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

1.By the time I got dismissed from military it has been ten years of being an officer.

2.When I got dismissed from military it had been ten years of being an officer.

Is it correct usage of present perfect and past perfect?

Comment: "...I had been an officer for ten years."

Comment: Is 1 not correct?

Comment: What I understand is 2 is more grammatical as you answered that when I got dismissed  I had been an officer for ten years.but how about 1 I can't use when I got dismissed I have been an officer for ten years.In 1 I want to emphasize that it was being officer ten years.

Comment: Neither is correct. You need an article before _military_ (when used as a noun, as it is here) and _officer_.

Comment: But I used AI grammar cheker.But it told my sentences are grammatically correct

Comment: Then it's no good as a grammar _checker_!

Comment: You need to use the past perfect here if you want to talk about the time before you were dismissed.  Also you have a missing indefinite article before "military".

Comment: Also note "It **told** my sentences are grammatically correct" is also incorrect.  "It **told me that** my . . ." or you can replace it with "said".  "It **said** my . . . "

Comment: Thank you very much Billy Kerr and Kate Bunting.

Comment: Now I got the answer by checker 1.I had been an officer for ten years in the past.2.It has been ten years of being an officer since I am dismissed.

Comment: "By the time I got dismissed from military, I had been an officer for ten years." "It has/had been <time period> of <activity>" is not idiomatic and I don't know where it comes from (your native language?).

Comment: I am From Myanmar.My level is B1.So I am weak in English.Pls give me examples so as to learn from all of you.

Comment: @Kate Bunting ,I know both are incorrect because I am weak in English and I will notice to put an article before noun.Pls give me some examples to learn present perfect and past perfect.As much as I can understand I wrote context and also I am hoping sutibale sentences for use of those tenses.I am B1 level.

Comment: @Stuart ,I imitated as "It's been a while".I thought I also could build sentences those duration in present perfect and past perfect.

Comment: _It has been ten years of being an officer since I am dismissed_ doesn't make sense - it suggests that you have been an officer for ten years _after_ leaving the army!

Comment: Thanks a lot@Kate Bunting.I really wanted to know how to express duration like "Its been a while"using present perfect. I know It was for ten years since I was dismissed but by using present perfect tense how to say I don't know.Thats why I asked.Thank you again.